# adding a sublayer to CALayer works only in mouseDown method

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I am trying to add a CALayer to an NSView.  The code I have which is not working is

```
-(void) InsertCALayer
{
    newLayer = [CALayer layer];
    newLayer.frame = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    newLayer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    [rootLayer addSublayer:newLayer];
}
```

However, nothing shows up with this code.  Oddly enough, I have also implemented a mouseDown event handler, and the code does work there:

```
-(void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{   
    newLayer = [CALayer layer];
    newLayer.frame = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    newLayer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    [rootLayer addSublayer:newLayer];
}
```

I can confirm that both methods definitely get called, but I am very confused as to why one works and the other doesn't.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the

```
-(void) InsertCALayer
```

method being called after the view heirarchy has loaded? If you set a breakpoint in the debugger in the InsertCaLayer method and 'po' rootLayer do you have a valid object?

The view heirarchy must be fully loaded before you make changes to it. I wonder if this is the problem here. Let me know!

Comment: aha! it seems that was the problem.  'po rootLayer' outputs a real memory address inside of the mouseDown method but inside InsertCALayer it is null.  Any idea how to force the view hierarchy to load before adding the layer? it seems strange that it isn't already loaded considering 'drawRect' is called several times before InsertCALayer

Comment: for future viewers of this post, the code
    
"if (!rootLayer)
    {
        rootLayer = [CALayer layer];
        [self setLayer:rootLayer];
        [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    }
"


seems to do the trick

Comment: that should do it! Note though if you have code elsewhere which sets the backing layer you should be clear as to which CALayer is actually being used as the rootLayer.